# How can you get the Sid Meier's Civilization V SDK to run?

Tags: visual-studio, civilization-modding

I'm trying to get the `Sid Meier's Civilization V SDK` to be able to do some improvements to the UI.
It is possible to install and run it from Steam Library after this checkbox is enabled from the `Games And Software` dropdown menu:

[image]

[image]

I am getting this error when trying to run it:

[image: Visual Studio 2010 Isolated Shell Redistributable is required]

`Visual Studio 2010 Isolated Shell Redistributable is required`

I already tried finding an installer from Microsoft, they force to create an azure account and it showed three files:

`en_visual_studio_2010_shell_isolated_.cat`
`en_visual_studio_2010_shell_isolated_.txt`
`mu_visual_studio_2010_sp1_x86_dvd.iso`

I mounted the .iso, ran Setup .exe and got this error:
[image]

So the Visual Studio 2010 installer requires Visual Studio 2010 to already be installed as an installation requirement! Thank you Microsoft.

Comment: It looks like that ISO is a service pack update, not the Visual Studio 2010 software. Did you try installing VS2010 separately first, then installing this ISO on top?